# refreshing text input value in jqMobi

Tags: jqmobi, jqui

I have a text input within a custom footer.  I am trying to update the text using:

```
$("#navbar #segment").val("blah");
```

I have also tried

```
$("#segment").val("blah");
```

both return objects, but neither show an updated text input.  The footer the input belongs to is not shown at the time, and I think this might have something to do with it since performing the same actions works when the panel is displayed.  I have also tried adding `$.ui.updateNavbarElements($("#navbar #segment"))` after each call and it throws an error.

Also, what is the difference between the jq.web.min.js included in the appMobi  XDK and the jqMobi script located on the CDN? Are they they same, and just the CDN is the latest?

Answer (score 0):

I was correct in assuming that changes are only reflected if the element is showing.

Comment: post this over at the jqmobi forums and I'll go into more detail.

Comment: Yup, will do.  Thanks Ian.